# Спрятать элемент с помощью скрипта

Tags: javascript

```
<td data-date="2017-02-30" style="text-align: center; height: 132.8px;"></td>
```

Есть этот элемент. Как мне ему сделать display none, если `data-date="2017-02-30"`

Comment: Как изменяется `data-table`? Или это где-то генерируется код и его надо преобразовать?

Answer (score 0):

```js
(function() {
  var td = document.querySelectorAll('table td'), // Получаем все td
      date = '2017-02-30'; // Нужная дата
  // Цикл всех td
  for(var i = 0; i < td.length; i++){
    var dateTd = td[i].getAttribute('data-date'); // Получаем содержимое атрибута data-date
    // Проверяем, равно ли значение из атрибута с переменной даты сверху
    if(dateTd == date){
      td[i].style.display = 'none'; // Если да, то скрываем td
    };
  };
}());
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td data-date="2017-02-30" style="text-align: center; height: 132.8px;">Блок 1</td></tr>
    <tr><td data-date="2017-02-31" style="text-align: center; height: 132.8px;">Блок 2</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Ваш код отлично работает, но на датах которые сейчас показываются в расписании (сайт http://puaroquest.ru/ - расписание ближе к концу страницы, но проблема в том, что дата нужна подгружается позже и на дате которая не видна не работает как надо. Посмотрите?

Comment: @Mimzik, почему бы вам не запускать эту функцию при каждой подгрузке дат? Или же проверять даты который подгружаются? Суть в том, что у вас в вопросе нет этих уточнений. Задавайте новый вопрос по этой теме

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/622382/Спрятать-элемент-в-помощью-скрипта-после-его-подгрузки