# Спрятать элемент в помощью скрипта после его подгрузки

Tags: javascript

```
<td data-date="2017-02-30"></td>
```

Есть расписание на сайте понедельное. Следующая неделя подгружаться при клике на ссылку с классом page-right. Нужно спрятать 3 дня в этом расписании, но они сразу недоступны при загрузке всей странице, а подгружаются позже

Есть этот элемент. Как мне ему сделать display none, если `data-date="2017-02-30"

Вот код, который прячет элемент при загрузке страницы. Как сделать, чтобы скрипт выполнялся каждый раз при нажатии на ссылку с классом page-right?

```
(function() {
  var td = document.querySelectorAll('table td'), // Получаем все td
  date = '2017-02-30'; // Нужная дата
  // Цикл всех td
  for(var i = 0; i < td.length; i++){
     var dateTd = td[i].getAttribute('data-date'); // Получаем содержимое       атрибута data-date
     // Проверяем, равно ли значение из атрибута с переменной даты сверху
    if(dateTd == date){
     td[i].style.display = 'none'; // Если да, то скрываем td
};
 };
 }());
```

Comment: когда добавляете новую неделю тогда и прячьте все что вам нужно

Answer (score 0):

```js
function hideTD() {
  var td = document.querySelectorAll('table td'), // Получаем все td
      date = '2017-02-30'; // Нужная дата
  // Цикл всех td
  for(var i = 0; i < td.length; i++){
    var dateTd = td[i].getAttribute('data-date'); // Получаем содержимое атрибута data-date
    // Проверяем, равно ли значение из атрибута с переменной даты сверху
    if(dateTd == date){
      td[i].style.display = 'none'; // Если да, то скрываем td
    };
  };
};

(function() {
  hideTD(); // Вызываем функцию при загрузке страницы
}());

document.querySelector('button').onclick = function() {
  document.querySelector('tbody').innerHTML = '<tr><td data-date="2017-02-30" style="text-align: center; height: 132.8px;">Блок 1</td></tr><tr><td data-date="2017-02-31" style="text-align: center; height: 132.8px;">Блок 2</td></tr>';
  hideTD(); // Вызываем функцию, что бы спрятать элементы
};
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td data-date="2017-02-30" style="text-align: center; height: 132.8px;">Блок 1</td></tr>
    <tr><td data-date="2017-02-31" style="text-align: center; height: 132.8px;">Блок 2</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button>Обновить таблицу</button>
```

Comment: `document.querySelector('page-right').onclick = function() {
  hideTD(); // Вызываем функцию, что бы спрятать элементы
}; `

или вот так `document.getElementsByClassName('page-right').onclick = function() {
  hideTD(); // Вызываем функцию, что бы спрятать элементы
}; `

и не работает

Comment: @Mimzik, вы хоть что-то в JS понимаете? Класс вводится так: `document.querySelector('.page-right').onclick`

Comment: @Mimzik, и `ClassName` выводит вам массив элементов, что бы он работал, нужно вписывать id элемента по клику на который будет совершаться нажатие

Comment: пробовал по всякому. Всё равно нету эффекта. Думаю, это может быть, когда при клике на расписание скрипт срабатывает сразу, а новая неделя ещё не успела подгрузиться

Comment: @Mimzik, так надо запускать, когда подгрузится..